# Initializing vector in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

I have a large vector `std::vector<some_class> some_vector` which I need to initialize with different values of constructors `some_class(constructor_parameters)`. The normal way to do it would be something like:

```
std::vector<some_class> some_vector
some_vector.reserve(length)

for (...) some_vector.push_back(some_class(constructor_parameters))
```

But because this vector is large, I want to do this in parallel. Is there any way to split the vector and `push_back` at q different position of the vector so each thread can start initializing a different part of the vector?

I read some answers with splitting / joining vector and haven`t found anything useful. As my vector is really large I have to avoid something like creating new vector for each thread and then copying them into the original one - I can use only one big chunk of memory.

I tried to use `some_vector.at(some_loc) =  some_class(constructor_parameters)` but this isn`t working with uninitialized vector.

I can initialize vector to some dump values and then use `at` to initiaize it to proper values, but it is not efficient.

**So my question** - *how to efficiently (in terms of memory consumption and computing time) initialize a large vector?*

**EDIT:** to answer comments:

*Size* - the container doesn`t change its size during the run of program, but the size is not known at compiling time. The size is huge because that's just the scope of the problem - I'm performing cosmological N-body simulation where number of particles / mesh cells can be easily 1024^3 and more.

*Ctors* - now they are just assigning values to class member (3 ~ 7 assignments) but I was planning to add some computation

*Members* - are easily coppyable, typically 2 `std::vector(3)`

*Why vectors* - I was originally using only basic type arrays and `new / delete` directive. I wanted to use vector because of their various functionalities, automatic memory (de)allocating, easier loop using iterators, etc. I just assumed that they should be easy to implement into multi thread with all their other good properties...

Comment: you could create a parallel_vector class holding n vectors and overloading operator[] to access the vectors using division/modulo. The initialization could be multithreaded, then, with 1 thread by internal vector.

Comment: Alternatively, you could construct a C-style array and do multithreaded initialisation on it, then use a custom allocator in your vector to which you pass the address.

Comment: What properties of the container do you need? Can it be fixed size? Is the size known at compile time? Are your ctors doing actual computational work or is it memory bandwidth bound? Is your type trivially copyable? Have you verified the initialization is CPU bound? If it turns out you really need to parallelize, I doubt vector is the best datastructure for your task. If you better define your required datastructure properties, people will be better able to suggest good alternatives.

Comment: maybe `std::vector` is not what you need then, maybe something like unrolled linked list is more appropriate.

Comment: also, it seems like an xy problem. why does the container has to be a vector , and why is it has to be huge? and what your program actually does?

Answer (score 1):

For general types `T`, the problem with what you describe is that it takes a fair amount of state to track which of the `T` have been constructed, and which have not.

If you compress the "is this a valid value" data into a bitfield, checking for validity is a very cache incoherent.

One easy approach is a `vector<optional<T>>` in C++17 or with boost.  Pre-size (to `nullopt`), then use `emplace` to construct the terms in whatever thread you want.

Finally, consider not using a single vector.  Write a wrapper that splices multiple vectors together into one visible container.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions I can think of.

One is to use a concurrent data structure, such as TBB's `concurrent_vector`. See its documents

The second is to write a custom allocator, whose `construct` member does not invoke the default constructor when called without arguments. And then allocate the vector once, and initialize each element in parallel. Care need to be taken to ensure that such a `construct` will not cause you troubles later. It will work best if you can use C++11 move semantics when you construct the new elements. In this case, the only thing you need to do in the master thread would be allocating the memory, a cost you can hardly avoid any way.

Here is a concrete example,

```
template <std::size_t n, std::size_t m>
class StirlingMatrix2
{
    public:
    StirlingMatrix2()
    {
        // compute the matrix of Stirling numbers
        // relatively expensive
    }

    double operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const
    {
        return data_[i * (m + 1) + j];
    }

    private:
    double data_[(n + 1) * (m + 1)];
}; // class StirlingMatrix

template <typename T, bool InvokeConstructor = true>
class Allocator
{
    public:
    // other member functions and types

    template <typename U>
    void construct(U *ptr)
    {
        construct_dispatch(
            ptr, std::integral_constant<bool, InvokeConstructor>());
    }

    template <typename U, typename Arg, typename... Args>
    void constrct(U *ptr, Arg &&arg, Args &&... args)
    {
        std::allocator<T>::construct(
            ptr, std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    private:
    template <typename U>
    void construct_dispatch(U *ptr, std::true_type)
    {
        std::allocator<T>::construct(ptr);
    }

    template <typename U>
    void construct_dispatch(U *, std::false_type)
    {
    }
}; // class Allocator

// specialization for void type is needed

int main()
{
    constexpr n = 100;
    constexpr m = 100;

    using T = StirlingMatrix2<n, m>;

    // each element will be constructed, very expensive
    std::vector<T> svec1(N);

    // allocate memory only
    std::vector<T, Allocator<T, false>> svec2(N);

    // within each thread
    // invoke inplace new to construct elements
}
```

For this to work, there cannot be pointer members, or class members that is not trivial. Otherwise there's no way to be exception safe. Similar technique can be used if you don't have to use a container class and instead is conformable with manually manage memory through `malloc`, etc.

Comment: Exceptions make your plan a bad idea; after `construct` the data will be destroyed in the event of an exception.  And if your data can stand destruction, how is it not constructed?

Comment: @Yakk That's for sure. That's why I said that care need to be taken to ensure that such a construct won't cause trouble later. Exception is not the only trouble it can run into. In some cases, depending on the data layout, this solution is not even possible.

Comment: @Yakk An object can stand destruction even when it's constructor wasn't invoked. For example, say it only contains integer/float data types, but their initial values are expensive to compute.

Comment: As far as I know, under the standard, no objedt may be destroyed without first being created in a well formed program.  Pseudo-destructors (such as `.~T()` when `T` is an `int`) do not destroy anything (no destructor occurs).  Invoking a destructor without a prior constructor is thus pointless, as you can construct an `int` in a way that does nothing?  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Yakk Your points is right, though not exactly what I meant by destroying an not constructed member. I wasn't very precise. For fundamental types, the default allocators `construct` member will zero out allocated space. That will take time. What's worse is that most compilers won't even optimize this zero out to `memset`. By "a `construct` that does not invoke constructor, what I meant was that an allocator that only allocate memory but does not invoke the in place `new` operator. A destructor is just a function called before the allocated memory was released, informatively.